# How do you disable javascript in python's mechanize?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mechanize

I don't know why, but I cant find it anywhere. All i need is the command to disable javascript in python's mechanize.

Comment: mechanize just uses the rendered html (like what you get when doing "view page source" in your browser), it does not interpret javascript.

Comment: @MatToufoutu Thanks! I'm learning more and more about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize doesn't deal with Javascript. It only take care of HTML. So you can't stop Javascript running using Mechanize. You need to find some other solution.

Comment: Isn't that more like 'you can't _start_ Javascript running using Mechanize'?